# Parallelograms formed by $m \times n$ parallel lines

Tags: combinatorics

> Consider that I have a set of $m$ parallel lines and another set of $n$ parallel lines. Now they are made to intersect forming multiple parallelograms. Now the question is how many **unique** parallelograms does these $m \times n$ parallel lines form.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: There are $m(m-1)/2$ pairs of parallel lines in one direction & $n(n-1)/2$ in the other direction. So there are $m(m-1)n(n-1)/4$ parallelograms.

Comment: That depends on the distances between the lines, no? E.g. if all the distances are the same you would get fewer kinds of parallelograms than when the distances are different ... are you maybe asking what the maximal number is? Or am I misunderstanding what you mean by *unique* parallelograms?

Comment: Perhaps the OP should define what a "unique" parallelogram means in this case. If they mean individually counting all the parallelograms that can be formed with the lines, then the answer provided by Jaideep and the comment provided by Donald is what the OP wants.

Comment: @WaveX Yeah I mean all the individual parallelograms that one can form.

Answer (score 5):

What forms a parallelogram? Two pairs of parallel sides.

OK. We're done.

Just select two lines from $m$ lines and two from $n$ lines. This type of selection will always result in a unique parallelogram, and obviously, won't leave any.

Therefore number of parallelogram $\displaystyle = \binom m2 \times  \binom n2=\frac{nm(n-1)(m-1)}{4}$